# Google Sheets onEdit(e) function keeps on running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google Sheets onEdit(e) function keeps on running using the previous code even if I modify it or delete it totally or even if I rename it to onEdit_DISABLED(e).

Why can I not apply changes to the script code of onEdit(e) function or why does it keep on running even if I delete it totally [by deleting project], the spreadsheet still keeps on reacting to this function and the previous script keeps on running.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?pli=1 and revoke access for your script.

Otherwise you might want to provide access to the spreadsheet (or a copy of it) so we can look into it in more detail.

Comment: Hi Vytautas, thank you for response. I figured it out, the problem was there was a dataValidation from the Spreadsheet that was overriding the code change that I wanted for cell background color.